# Collision detection on a tweened object

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I cann't get it to work, seems like tweened objects don't fire the 'Moved' event?

I'm tweening a object across the screen, and need to check if it collided with the player (that flies up and down by the keyboard events). It works if I append the check on 'Moved' for the player, but what if the player stands still :-)

So I need to check when the tweened objects moves if it hit the player

Does not fire any of the events:

```
        // astroid
        Crafty.e('astroid, 2D, DOM, Color, Tween, Collision')
            .attr({ x: 600, y: 550, w: 50, h: 200 })
            .color('#8e44ad')
            .tween({ x: -50 }, 4000)
            .bind('Moved', function () {

                console.log('moved');

                if (this.hit('player1')) {
                    console.log('player hit 1');
                }
            })
            .onHit('player', function () {
                console.log('player hit 2');
            });
```

Comment: Are you able to provide your http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Ashish Mishra yes I am :-) http://jsfiddle.net/6RDYw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated :**

I am using little `plugin` Here ,`collisions($div1, $div2)`:

So,

```
 function interval() {

   timeout = setTimeout(function () {

        if (collisions($('.player1'), $('.astroid'))) {
           alert('true');

        }
        else{
            interval();
        }
    }, 25);

 }

 interval()
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/6RDYw/4/)

May this was helpful ...

Comment: This won't be compatible with Crafty's built-in collision stuff, though!  I'd assume it would also fail if you switched from DOM to Canvas.

Comment: I give solution ,according to above condition ,and i am not test it for canvas,may be it fails on canvas,but it work for HTML element  ! @starwed

Comment: Sure, but the OP is already using a [game framework](http://craftyjs.com/) that provides this functionality; there's no reason for them to pull in additional dependencies that aren't compatible.  :)

Comment: @starwed ,ya you right,but whatever i know to achieve above task,i just shared here !,And really i don't know anything about this tween/crafty plugin! :) anyway, If you wanna edit and have better answer then your welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

"Moved" is a special event that the components like "Multiway" use.

The more fundamental event is just "Move", which is implemented directly by the [2D component](http://craftyjs.com/api/2D.html)  -- bind to that event instead.

What many people do is just check for collisions once per frame using "EnterFrame".  If you need to act *directly* after the collision, binding to "Move" will provide that, though.

Comment: ,Please add any running example of `collision detection` with `craftyJs` ,because i searched alot but nothing find...it !